# How to display a JavaScript array in HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml, imagefilter

I have a JavaScript application that applies filters to a live video.

I was wondering how I can display what the current filter is using inner.HTML after the user hits the filter button.

I want to display the current filter (sepia, grayscale etc) in here

```
<p id="filterName"></p>
```

Here is my code which changes the filter, I feel I have to put the line of code to display the filter at the end as part of the filter button function.

```
 // CSS filters 
    //this array will cycle through the filter effects
    var index = 0; //the array starts at 0
    var filters = ['grayscale', 'sepia', 'saturate', 'hue', 'invert', 'no-filter'];



    // this applies the filter to the video feed, takes the class of the video feed
    var changeFilter = function () {
        var el = document.getElementById('video');
        el.className = 'videoClass';

        //this will cycle through the filters, once it hits the final filter it will reset
        var effect = filters[index++ % filters.length]
        if (effect) {
            el.classList.add(effect);
            console.log(el.classList);
        }
    }

    //when the user presses the filter button it will apply the first filter in the array
    document.getElementById('filterButton').addEventListener('click', changeFilter);
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I have a second question, I added another filter called no-filter (it adds clear). How can I have that be displayed at the start. As of now it only displays after I cycle through the other filters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it is simple as this, isn't it?

```
var changeFilter = function () {
    ...
    var effect = filters[index++ % filters.length]
    ...
    document.getElementById('filterName').innerHTML=effect;
}
```

Another suggestion: You'd better update the `index` variable before indexing the array:

```
index=index++ % filters.length;
var effect=filters[index];
```

You have correctly avoided the indexing value exceding the array's bounds, but you must also avoid the `index` variable exceed the *maximum integer bound*.

---

If you wanted to set some of the filters as the initial filter, I recommend you to do it through these steps:

1.Take out all of the `changeFilter`'s logic (except incrementing `index`) to a new function to update the filter:

```
function updateFilter()
{
    var el = document.getElementById('video');
    el.className = 'videoClass';

    var effect = filters[index];
    if (effect) {
        el.classList.add(effect);
        console.log(el.classList);
    }
    document.getElementById('filterName').innerHTML=effect;
}
```

2.Replace the body of `changeFilter` to delegate to the new function:

```
var changeFilter = function () {
    index=++index  % filters.length;  // pre-increment is better
    updateFilter();
}
```

In this way, you have separated the action of updating the filter from the action of changing the filter, so you can reuse it better.

3.Initialize properly the index variable to the desired initial filter:

```
var index = 5;
```

4.At the end of the script, call `updateFilter` the first time. This will put the current filter (which initially is the 5th index).

Comment: where would I place it? I'm still learning JavaScript. Would I add it as part of my filter button?

Comment: Will it really work? Won't the JS engine convert it to string and then you'll just see "Object Array" as value...

Comment: At the end of `changeFilter`'s body. I've updated my answer.

Comment: @StrandedKid Hum... Yes, it will work: `effect` was initialized from the content of one of the array's indexes. So, it contains a string.

Comment: @LittleSanti Ok my bad did not read the OP post carefully, I thouhg he wanted to display the whole array content.

Comment: @LittleSanti Thank you it works! I have a second question though. I added another filter called no-filter (it adds clear). How can I have that be displayed at the start. I can have it displayed at the end as of now.

Comment: @NAFarr Hum... If you want the video be _initially_ displayed with the "no-filter" filter, I guess it would be enough to form the HTML with this initial class: `<video class="videoClass no-filter" >`

Comment: @LittleSanti But how would it display in the <p id="filterName"></p> no-filter? Would I be able some how have that show "no-filter" as a default? I'm still getting used to JavaScript.

Comment: Thank you so much, you have taught me a lot about JS